# How do I get the RootViewController from a pushed controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

So, I push a view controller from RootViewController like:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES] ;
```

BUT, FROM `anotherViewController` now, I want to access the RootViewController again.

I'm trying

```
// (inside anotherViewController now)
///RootViewController *root = (RootViewController*)self.parentViewController ; // No.
// err
RootViewController *root = (RootViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] ; // YES!! it works
```

I'm not sure WHY this works and I'm not sure if its the best way to do it.  Can somebody comment on a better way to get the RootViewController from a controller you've pushed into that RootViewController's navigationController and whether or not the way I've done it is reliable or not?

Comment: What you've done will reliably get the root view controller (the first one in the navigation hierarchy), if you want to get access to the "back" view controller, see my answer.

Comment: [See also "What does setting the UIWindow's rootViewController do?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204059/what-does-setting-the-uiwindows-rootviewcontroller-do)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Use the [viewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers) property of the UINavigationController. Example code:

```
// Inside another ViewController
NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
UIViewController *rootViewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];
```

This is the standard way of getting the "back" view controller. The reason `objectAtIndex:0` works is because the view controller you're trying to access is also the root one, if you were deeper in the navigation, the back view would not be the same as the root view.

Comment: :) ty.  It still seems hacky - :) I really wanted an "official" member to do the job, something like self.navigationController.rootViewController, but alas, no such thing..

Comment: The code above is erroneous. `rootViewController` is missing `*` before it, and the index should just be `0`. The code in the question is correct: `RootViewController *root = (RootViewController *)[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]`

Comment: Agreed: the above code returns the *parent* view controller, not the *root* view controller as the OP asked. Still, that's what Ben S said he'll do, he just didn't point that out enough.

Comment: The 2nd line should read: UIViewController *rootViewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 1];

Answer (score 185):

Swift version :

```
var rootViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first
```

ObjectiveC version :

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers firstObject];
```

Where self is an instance of a UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController.

Comment: Can I get navigationController of another ViewController from a different class?

Comment: Any UIViewController subclass will have a navigationController property, which points to it's first parentViewController matching UINavigationController class.

Answer (score 13):

A slightly less ugly version of the same thing mentioned in pretty much all these answers:

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] firstObject];
```

in your case, I'd probably do something like:

**inside your UINavigationController subclass**:

```
- (UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    return [[self viewControllers] firstObject];
}
```

then you can use:

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.navigationController rootViewController];
```

**edit**

OP asked for a property in the comments.

if you like, you can access this via something like `self.navigationController.rootViewController` by just adding a readonly property to your header:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) UIViewController *rootViewController;
```

Answer (score 9):

For all who are interested in a swift extension, this is what I'm using now:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    var rootViewController : UIViewController? {
        return self.viewControllers.first
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also you can remove "as? UIViewController"

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to [@dulgan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16340179/793428) answer, it is always a good approach to use `firstObject` over `objectAtIndex:0`, because while first one returns nil if there is no object in the array, latter one throws exception.

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = self.navigationController.rootViewController;
```

Alternatively, it'd be a big plus for you to create a category named `UINavigationController+Additions` and define your method in that.

```
@interface UINavigationController (Additions)

- (UIViewController *)rootViewController;

@end

@implementation UINavigationController (Additions)

- (UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    return self.viewControllers.firstObject;
}

@end
```

Comment: I just added this part without reading your answer, you're totally right with the "firstObject" being better thant [0]

Answer (score 2):

I encounter a strange condition.

`self.viewControllers.first` is not root viewController always.

Generally, `self.viewControllers.first` is root viewController indeed. But sometimes it's not.

```
class MyCustomMainNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    function configureForView(_ v: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        let root = self.viewControllers.first
        let isRoot = (v == root)
    
        // Update UI based on isRoot
        // ....
    }
}

extension MyCustomMainNavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, 
        willShow viewController: UIViewController, 
        animated: Bool) {

        self.configureForView(viewController, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

#### My issue:

Generally, `self.viewControllers.first` is `root` viewController.
But, when I call `popToRootViewController(animated:)`, and then it triggers `navigationController(_:willShow:animated:)`. At this moment, `self.viewControllers.first` is NOT root viewController, it's the last viewController which will disappear.

#### Summary

- `self.viewControllers.first` is not always `root` viewController.  Sometime, it will be the last viewController.

So, I suggest to keep `rootViewController` by property when `self.viewControllers` have ONLY one viewController. I get root viewController in `viewDidLoad()` of custom UINavigationController.

```
class MyCustomMainNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    fileprivate var myRoot: UIViewController!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // My UINavigationController is defined in storyboard. 
        // So at this moment, 
        // I can get root viewController by `self.topViewController!`
        let v = self.topViewController!
        self.myRoot = v
    }

}
```

#### Enviroments:

- iPhone 7 with iOS 14.0.1
- Xcode 12.0.1 (12A7300)

Comment: I am seeing this as well, old legacy code failed ~!!!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller

The root view controller becomes the top view controller. 

That's why it does not work in navigationController(_ , willShow, animated:)

Comment: @CiNN, it needs some tests. Generally, `willShow` contains keyword `will`, so, I guess the view hierarchies should be un-changed by the naming style in Apple APIs.

Comment: well do documentation says so, I tried and it works as described in the documentation. I tried to find something but nothing without having a temporary value.

Answer (score 1):

How about asking the [UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for its [keyWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/keyWindow), and from that [UIWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) ask for the root view controller (its [rootViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController) property):

```
UIViewController root = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
```

Comment: how to get navigation controller ?

Comment: This is a wrong suggestion as what if my rootviewcontroller of application is UITabBarViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Here I came up with universal method to navigate from any place to root.

1. You create a new Class file with this class, so that it's accessible from anywhere in your project:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class SharedControllers
   {
       static func navigateToRoot(viewController: UIViewController)
       {
           var nc = viewController.navigationController

           // If this is a normal view with NavigationController, then we just pop to root.
           if nc != nil
           {
               nc?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
               return
           }

           // Most likely we are in Modal view, so we will need to search for a view with NavigationController.
           let vc = viewController.presentingViewController

           if nc == nil
           {
               nc = viewController.presentingViewController?.navigationController
           }

           if nc == nil
           {
               nc = viewController.parentViewController?.navigationController
           }

           if vc is UINavigationController && nc == nil
           {
               nc = vc as? UINavigationController
           }

           if nc != nil
           {
               viewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:
                   {
                       nc?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
               })
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Usage from anywhere in your project:

   ```
   {
       ...
       SharedControllers.navigateToRoot(self)
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

### This worked for me:

When my root view controller is embedded in a navigation controller:

```
UINavigationController * navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] rootViewController];
RootViewController * rootVC = (RootViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] firstObject];
```

Remember that `keyWindow` is deprecated.