# What does setting the UIWindow's rootViewController do?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

> Assigning a view controller to this property (either programmatically
>   or using Interface Builder) installs the view controller’s view as the
>   content view of the window.

The above quote is from the UIWindow's reference.  My question is about the particular phase :

> "installs the view controller’s view as the
>   content view of the window"

What does exactly content view refer to ?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Before the `rootViewController` property came along, most apps had code like this in the application delegate:

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This code set the view controller's view as the main view, but the UIWindow instance had no reference to the controller owning that view.

When you use the `rootViewController` property, you don't need to add the view controller's view to the UIWindow instance anymore, this is done automatically. So the number of lines of code stays the same, but now your UIWindow has a reference to the view controller.

So, in newer applications, we now have code that looks like this:

```
window.rootViewController = viewController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: +1 for comprehensive answer taking historical reasoning into account

Comment: Note that it's available in 4.0+

Comment: @CanBerkGüder is it true only rootviewcontroller will get the callback functions like didReceivememoryWarning?

Comment: @S.J Each of the view controllers pushed to the navigation controller receives the `didReceivememoryWarning` invocation. Try it yourself and see. Implement the `didReceivememoryWarning` method, have that method call NSLog, then simulate the low memory condition in the iOS Simulator.