# iPhone - Animating "back" to parent controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

I want to implement a "Next" feature in my app.  The button appears on a `ViewController` that is shown by clicking on a row in a `UITableView`. Ideally what I would like is for Next to do the following (in pseudo code)

1. Go "back" to the `UITableView`
2. Scroll to next available item in `UITableView`
3. Select that item

I believe I can do 2,3 via `selectRowAtIndexPath` (please feel free to correct me if I am wrong) but I am unsure how to do Step 1.  I will also have to target a method in the `UITableView` rather than the `UIViewController` that hosts the Button.  How would I achieve this?

**Update:**

I can now target the rootViewController but now do I actually show it? (For reference here is my code, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792858/how-do-i-get-the-rootviewcontroller-from-a-pushed-controller))

```
NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
UIViewController *rootViewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];

UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:rootViewController action:@selector(nextButton:)];
```

**Update 2**

I now have the back animation working but it keeps the navigation bar intact, how do I also set this back to the correct (rootViewController) one?

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: So when you click the row, you are pushing a new view controller, but why are you doing a popToRootViewController? Don't you just want to go back one view controller?

Comment: When I click a row a new view is shown, then "Next" is pressed in this new view it navigates back to the rootViewController (a UITableView) and selects the next row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have situation like this:

1. RootViewController - tableView
2. NextviewController - some view with Next button which shows after the you click on tableView

When you issue [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; from the 2. controller by pressing the Next button, it will bring RootViewController to the screen.

Now, on the RootViewController you have to "detect" back action (perhaps in ViewWillAppear) and continue with your steps 2. and 3.