# How can I get the rootViewController of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, rootviewcontroller

I want to get the rootViewController of UINavigationController. It works in Objective-c, but when I use it in Swift , the error reminds me that it was wrong.

[Code screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUrJ3.png).

If I do this, add `as! NSArray`, it works, but also reminds me that "cast from '[UIViewController]' to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fails".

[Code screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THB3J.png)

Can somebody show a better way to get the `rootViewController`` without error. Thank you.

Comment: this is `let homevci = navigationController!.viewControllers!.first as! NBHomeVC`

Comment: but better way, you need to read some swift documentation. it is not objc-c :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667009/get-top-most-uiviewcontroller

Comment: It works, thank you , I think I should think about the difference between [UIViewController] and array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64256611/419348

Answer (score 51):

You can get the root by,

```
self.navigationController!.viewControllers.first
```

Answer (score 22):

Or as an extension:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    var rootViewController : UIViewController? {
        return viewControllers.first
    }
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
if let rootv = navigationController?.rootViewController { }
```

Comment: Nice answer, but `as? UIViewController` can be removed because `first` already returns a `UIViewController?`. Also, in your second code snippet it should be `navigationController?.rootViewController` as it's an optional.

Comment: @nyg: Thanks for spotting it, I'm sure it worked at some point in the past, but too many Swift versions came and went ... It should work now in Swift 4.

Answer (score 4):

Or maybe this can be used

```
self.navigationController.visibleViewController
```

or

```
self.navigationController.topViewController
```

Comment: This is not the root view controller , This is the top view controller in the navigation controller stack , `topViewController` will be the root view controller if the navigation controller did not push any view controllers .

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
let homevci = controllerArray.objectAtIndex(0) as? NBHomeVC
```

with

```
let homevci = controllerArray.first as? NBHomeVC
```

or

```
let homevci = controllerArray[0] as? NBHomeVC
```